# Finding $\sum (-1)^k(\frac{1}{3^k})\binom{n}{2k+1} $

Tags: combinatorics

I want to find the sum $C(n,1) - (1/3)C(n,3) + (1/9)C(n,5) - (1/27)C(n,7) + ... $ which can be written as $\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k(\frac{1}{3^k})\binom{n}{2k+1} $. I don't have any nice ideas on how to solve this other than by bashing it with calculation which definitely not nice.

Can anyone provide ideas?

Comment: Maybe use $\frac{(1+ix)^n-(1-ix)^n}{2i}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Why do you suggest that / where do that fraction come from?

Comment: The division is not interesting,  The point is that $(1+xi)^n$ is $1+i\binom{n}{1}x-\binom{n}{2}x^2-i\binom{n}{3}x^3+\cdots$. Write down a similar expression for $(1-xi)^n$, subtract, and note that we get more or less what you wrote down except multiplied by $2i$.

Answer (score 2):

Often in mathematics, it's easier to solve a more general problem than to do the special case directly. So suppose $n$ is given. Then we denote
$$A_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{n}{2k+1}x^k$$
Note that we can let $k$ run to infinity since for $k>\frac{n}{2}$ the binomial coefficients will all be 0 and our sum won't change.

Note that $xA_n(x^2)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{n}{2k+1}x^{2k+1}$ looks pretty much like the sum from the binomial theorem. What exactly is missing?

It's $B(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{n}{2k}x^{2k}$.

So $xA_n(x^2)+B(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{n}{k} x^k=(1+x)^n$ by the binomial theorem.
Now, we can use a trick to evaluate $B(x)$.
Note that
$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{n}{k}x^k$$
and
$$(1-x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{n}{k}x^k$$
So we can write $B(x)=\frac{1}{2}((1+x)^n+(1-x)^n$. Do you see why? (This is actually the same idea as suggested by **André Nicolas** in his comment).

So we find $xA(x^2)=\frac{1}{2}((1+x)^n-(1-x)^n)$ and hence
$$A(x)=\frac{(1+\sqrt{x})^n-(1-\sqrt{x})^n}{2\sqrt{x}}$$

Now let's return to the original problem:

The desired sum is just the same as $A(-\frac{1}{3})$ which hopefully you can evaluate by yourself..

Answer (score 0):

The application of the discrete Fourier transform, as shown by Tintarn, is the usual technique for evaluating such sums. An alternative approach is to exploit the usual properties of binomial coefficients in order to prove a recursive relation for:
$$ A_n = \sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{n}{2k+1}\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^k,$$
like $A_{n+2}=k_1\cdot A_{n+1}+k_0\cdot A_n$.
That gives a strong analogy between $A_n$ and the Fibonacci number $F_n$. I leave to you to fill the details.